# Searching element in unknown size array

Tags: arrays, pseudocode, binary-search

Given an **N** sorted elements in the beginning of an infinite array, find if a given **k** elements exists in the array in **O(logN)** time, or return proper message if element does not exist.

What i have come up with so far is a modification of binary search since we dont know the length of array(we know its infinite but we dont know N) i use this:

```
if k > A[i] then let i = i*2
If k == A[i], then we re done, otherwise we do binary search as usual on A[1..i].
```

The only problem is that with this pseudocode i am afraid the time it will take to make the search will be higher than O(logN) since there is a chance that we will run multiple binary searches so its gonna be something of O(klogN).

Any ideas??

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Given an array of unknown size, of  N (unknown) sorted elements(lets say from high to low) can you find if a k elements exists in the array in O(logN) using binary search ?? Or in general you can use a Divide & Conquer technique.

Comment: Can we assume that, after the N sorted elements, the array contains only zeros? (Or some other value easily distinguished from the N sorted elements; perhaps MAXINT)? If so, then your approach should work with a few tweaks. As long as you only run some constant number of binary searches -- I suspect there is a way to do it with at most 4 binary searches -- then the total run time is O(4 log N) or similar which is equivalent to O(log N), in the same way that O( 42 ) is equivalent to O(1).